# The Curie-Weiss model from Ising

Tags: network

Can anyone explain why this is the case?

$$
\begin{aligned}
p(\mathbf{x}) &=\frac{\exp \left\{\sum_{i=1}^{n} \mu_{i} x_{i}+\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} \sigma x_{i} x_{j}\right\}}{\sum_{\mathbf{x}} \exp \left\{\sum_{i=1}^{n} \mu_{i} x_{i}+\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} \sigma x_{i} x_{j}\right\}} \\
&=\frac{\exp \left\{\sum_{i=1}^{n} \mu_{i} x_{i}+\sigma x_{+}^{2}\right\}}{\sum_{\mathbf{x}} \exp \left\{\sum_{i=1}^{n} \mu_{i} x_{i}+\sigma x_{+}^{2}\right\}},
\end{aligned}
$$
in which $x_+ = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} x_i$ refers to the sum of the node states

Answer (score 0):

because
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} x_{i} x_{j}
&= x_1^2 + x_1x_2 + x_1x_3 + \dots + x_1x_n \\
&+ x_1x_2 +x_2^2+x_2x_3+ \dots x_2x_n\\
&  +  \dots  + \\
& x_1x_n+x_2x_n+ x_3x_n+ \dots  + x_n^2 \\
&= (x_1+x_2 +  \dots  + x_n)(x_1+x_2 +  \dots  + x_n)\\
&=(x_1+x_2 +  \dots  + x_n)^2.
\end{aligned}
$$